# Prevent EditText from taking speacial characters

Tags: android

I have an edittext which takes some user input I have a regex to allow a-z A-Z 0-9 @-_ I want to prevent the user from typing any other character except this regex. for now, my code is working fine if a user enters a character except this regex the edittext shows error but I want that user should not be able to type other characters except this regex.

here's my code to check the regex.

```
editTextUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();

            String localeKeyboard = ims.getLocale();

            if(localeKeyboard.equalsIgnoreCase(LocaleManager.LANGUAGE_ARABIC)){
                editTextUsername.setError(null);
            }
            else{
                if(UtilHelper.isValidNameSubject(editTextUsername.getText().toString())){
                    editTextUsername.setError(null);
                }
                else{
                    editTextUsername.setError(getString(R.string.txt_invalid_name));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is my regex,

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9ء-ي@_ -]*$"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this in your `TextWatcher`

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      String text = s.toString();
      int length = text.length();

      if(length > 0 && !Pattern.matches(YOUR_REGEX, text)) {
           s.delete(length - 1, length);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:digits` to your xml, put your symbols instead of abcd

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:digits="abcd" />
```

Comment: my app is bilingual it also converts in Arabic so if I add anything in android: digits it will not take Arabic characters from the keyboard. in my regex i have added Arabic

Comment: You can get it from string resource file for Arabic